# promise {<pending>} - async function return await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Why does the following only show me `Promise { <pending> }`

```
const Binance = require('binance-api-node').default;
const Client = Binance({
    apiKey: binanceAPIKey,
    apiSecret: binanceAPISecret
});

async function checkBTCAvgPriceLast24h() {
    return await Client.dailyStats({symbol: "BTCEUR"});
}

console.log(checkBTCAvgPriceLast24h());
```

shouldn't `await` wait till resolved or rejected?

Comment: You need to await on `checkBTCAvgPriceLast24h()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2):

Because an `async` function itself returns a `Promise`, and your code is not waiting for it to resolve.

Try chaining your function call with `.then()` and it should work.

```
checkBTCAvgPriceLast24h().then(res => console.log(res));
```

See the code snippet below for better understanding:

```js
const someAsyncTask = () =>
  new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res("Here's your data");
    }, 1000);
  });

async function main() {
  return await someAsyncTask();
}

main().then((res) => console.log(res));
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Your explanation makes sense but I have tried and still getting `Promise { <pending> }`

Comment: Are you sure about the correctness of the code above?

Comment: Well I'm a beginner but it should be correct as you can see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/binance-api-node#avgPrice). They're doing the same but with `console.log()` on the `dailyStats` method

Comment: Try this: `async function checkBTCAvgPriceLast24h() { console.log(await Client.dailyStats({symbol: "BTCEUR"})) }` and just call the function `checkBTCAvgPriceLast24h()`. See if you get any logs.

Comment: well if I run from terminal with `node binance-bot.js` it still only shows `Promise { <pending> }`

Comment: It works for me, I tried it on my system without the keys. Make sure you're doing everything correctly. Copy the code they have on their npm page and try running it, see if that works.